# Modern Markup for lengthy novel suited for self-publishing

Tags: formatting, self-publishing, software, kindle, markup-languages

I wrote a lengthy novel using a program I wrote.
This produces a suitable LaTeX source I can use to generate a nice-looking PDF.

Markup, beside customary division in Part/Chapter/Scene, is used to put emphasis, to handle direct-speech (which I use a lot, sometimes even nested) and to output certain phrases in "strange fonts".

So far, so good.

Now my problem is I need to convert all this into a format suitable for Kindle as I want to self-publish with Amazon.

I have seen standard tools (i.e.: Kindle Create), but that seems to lack all the kinds of formatting I'm using and its input (if I want to enable reflow) is restricted to Microsoft .docx format, which I don't know how to produce.

OTOH I have control over my program so, given a suitable markup (e.g.: Markdown) I can generate what is needed.

Question is: which "suitable markup" is available for novel rendering?

Ideally it should:

- handle standard headings (easy; almost every markup does).
- handle TOC and some limited cross-referencing (this is also standard).
- handle font change "on the fly" (font face, not just bold/italic).
- handle (possibly nested) direct speech, possibly keeping track of speaker.
- output a professional-looking ebook for Kindle (mobi, epub or azw3/4).
- if possible generate, from the same source, also PDF (not mandatory).

Does such a beast exist?

---

UPDATE:

judging from comments and the lonely Answer I did not manage to make the message through (or I'm saying something completely foolish, which could well be).

What I really like in LaTeX is it's possible to use things like `\tqt{Yesterday my boss said: \tqt{jump!} and I had to jump.}` to define a (nested) direct speech fragment and it will be converted according Your (global) choices.

In my book I use:

```
«Yesterday my boss said: “jump!” and I had to jump.»
```

but that could be easily (and globally!) converted to a different style, e.g.:

```
— Yesterday my boss said: «jump!» and I had to jump.
```

This (again AFAIK) is possible neither in plain HTML nor with programs normally used to edit books (MSWord, kindle-create, Calibre or Sigil).

Other uses of semantic tagging could include:

- differentiating (visually or otherwise) speech from different entities (e.g.: speech from a vampire could be in a different font)
- long citations.
- nested tales (e.g.: flashbacks).
- separators (horizontal line vs. stars vs. graphic image).
- add "invisible" metadata (e.g.: time and duration of a scene, to be used to prepare a timeline).
- etc.

"Normal" markup languages (e.g.: Markdown) are not really suited for this even if they have a lots of features, mostly useless for novel writing (cross-reference, lists, tables, math, ...).

I am thinking about defining (and implementing) something myself.

Let me know if there is some interest.

Any comment welcome.

Comment: This is a better question for tex.se. See [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1551/use-latex-to-produce-epub) question.

Comment: @J.G.: I have been on that road and I can assure You it gets nowhere (at least for me): NONE of the zillion "solutions" proposed seems able to deal with Font changing. ALL solutions seem to concern with math rendering, which I don't need, and not with novel writing. That is exactly the reason why I'm exploring the possibility to ditch LaTeX in favor of some other markup, if possible. Alternative is manually import everything into MSWord and reformat from scratch (forgetting about semantic tagging). Question is: is there a markup language designed for novel writing?

Comment: I'm not sure what to advise, then. I write my novels in LyX, which has its own .lyx file format, from which you have to export to another filetype for people without LyX to read. It can also import LaTeX, after which you can export either to .pdf (which you already have) or .docx, then convert that to .epub with another program. But hopefully there's a better solution.

Comment: You might have better luck looking into producing OpenDocument (which Word can open, or you could use another piece of software that understands OpenDocument and can create .docx files to do the conversion), and then set up a way to convert OpenDocument to Word. That said, I'm not sure if OpenDocument qualifies as "markup", though it is XML (as is .docx).

Comment: Is the document export your only concern? There's a number of options to convert from LaTeX to Word - are they all so awful? Also, suppose you can find a tool that handles font change smartly and smoothly - but how would that help when a reader changes font on his/her Kindle?

Comment: In my opinion is better to think this with the end goal in mind: creating a well set up Ebook or the device in mind. Formatting greatly matters, even if a reader later changes the font/size: for example, when I have to convert .pdf or .doc to .epub , if I forget to adjust it in the Ebook converter, it would suck no matter how much I would adjust the Ebook reader settings. I hope the program I mentioned in my answer can be helpful.

Comment: "Modern Markup" there seems to refer to a specific language but Google's idea what that might be is no more clear than mine. What did you mean by "Modern Markup", please?

Are you not trying to re-invent the wheel?

"Markup, beside customary division in Part/Chapter/Scene, is used to put emphasis, to handle direct-speech (which I use a lot, sometimes even nested) and to output certain phrases in 'strange fonts'…" reads as the vaguest description of all editing/DTP/markup/WP apps, with no palpable specifics.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin: if you are aware of a "editing/DTP/markup/WP app" able to correctly render (both in editor and in print) several kinds of direct speech (normal, thinking, ghost, beast, etc.) and to highlight on screen occurrences of character names I would be very interested in a pointer. TiA

Comment: @TiA Of course not.

Your "editing/DTP/markup/WP app" would be, eg, QuarkXPress of Adobe InDesign but neither give a rat's whisker about correct rendering, whatever you mean by "both in editor and in print"

How could any software… or any human editor… recognise your normal, thinking, ghost, beast, etc, kinds of direct speech?

How could any software… highlight occurrences of character names?

Design such a thing and you will become very, very rich, very, very quickly.

Comment: Could you go back and say what you meant by "Modern Markup", please? 

Could you go back and explain what difference the length of your makes, or that it's a novel, or that it's suited for self-publishing?

How could any of that matter to any writing, printing or publishing software?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin: "How could any software… or any human editor… recognise your normal, thinking, ghost, beast, etc, kinds of direct speech? How could any software… highlight occurrences of character names?" - if I interpret the question correctly, that's precisely where the *markup* comes in: Special tags in between the normal text are not rendered as output, but rather *tell* the software that "the following line is spoken by a ghost", "the following word is a character name", etc., whereupon the software applies the appropriate formatting.

Comment: @F-H Sorry, this is not amusing.

If you or ZioByte can explain what's really being Asked here, please do.

Until then, how do you define "Modern…" as opposed to any other markup used in the last 500 years?

How do you think the subject being "a lengthy novel" changes anything?

How do you think the subject being "suited for self-publishing" changes anything?

Broadly you do correctly interpret correctly that "markup" defines typography and beyond that simple fact, what are you suggesting?

Comment: Where does "editing/DTP/markup/WP…" able to correctly render (both in editor and in print) several kinds of speech (normal, thinking, ghost, beast, etc.) and highlight screen occurrences of character names…" come in?

What is "both in editor and in print"?

How could "normal, thinking, ghost, beast…" matter to a markup language? "Style 1, Style 2…" yes, and do you see no difference?

I suggest no markup language can handle those differences without you inputting details.

Any number of word processors - as eg, MS Word - can handle such differences and word processing is not marking up.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin: I cannot answer any of the questions from your first comment. I only have a hunch about the part that I referred to, namely markup for different kinds of speech + names highlight. To give an example: 'How could "normal, thinking, ghost, beast…" matter to a markup language?' - the markup could be `Alfred said: {ghost:Boohoo!} Margaret did not like this: {beast:Roarrrr!}`. This could be rendered into an output like: "Alfred said: “Boohoo!” Margaret did not like this: *«Roarrrr!»*" Of course, the information how "ghost", "beast", and all the others would be rendered ...

Comment: ... - mere styling, such as using small-caps, italic, different fonts, etc.; insertion/replacement of characters, such as using quotation marks vs. guillemets, etc. -, has to be supplied separately, as an additional input beside the markup text itself.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin: I suspect the central source of confusion is your assumption that all of this should work "without you inputting details". I do not think that is a requirement in the question as asked. It's not about the software somehow guessing how it should render something, but about the author not being bothered by how something will be rendered while writing. The "semantic tagging", as mentioned in the question, should be sufficient; which semantics equal which concrete output can be decided later on - thereby following the principle of "separation of content and presentation".

Comment: F-H I'm sorry to have to point this out, and you seem to be attempting not just to modify or improve standard markup notation, but to completely redefine both the notation and it's purpose.

If that's what you want fine, and why not say so?

If that's not what you want, what have I missed?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin: What is "standard markup notation"? There are many different markup notations, with many different capabilities and different purposes. As far as I gather from the question and the OP's own answer, they are simply looking for *a* markup notation that has been defined with the very purpose in mind of representing story structure (chapters, paragraphs, ...), direct speech (nested blocks, and different styles), and highlighting of special terms (character names), plus some more aspects.

Comment: Sorry still not to understand and please, which of ZioByte's stated ideals does anyone think MS Word won't handle?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin: How do you achieve the switch between direct speech styles shown in the question in Word, for instance? Taking the example from the question, how do you tell Word that the sentence *Yesterday my boss said: jump! and I had to jump.* is direct speech, and that in there, *jump!* is nested direct speech, in such a way that Word automatically places the correct marks like «» and “”? Later on, how do you have Word change the style of direct speech markings, such that the outer direct speech is just prefixed with a long dash and the inner direct speech is enclosed in «»?

Comment: @F-H It seems you want to re-shape the wheel, as oval. 

No switch between 'direct speech styles' exists, but an author chooses French or goodies in red, English or baddies in white and others in blue.

'Yesterday my boss said: jump!' is not direct; it's reported speech, wrongly punctuated.

What might 'nested direct speech' mean in English writing or editing, printing or general publishing?

How could an app place marks like «» and “” and why should an app be asked to?

What need could there be for a markup language to interfere with the changes you're talking about?

Comment: @F-H; ZioByte Can neither of you just try using MS Word or any other modern word processor, instead of trying to imagine why Word might not help you?

If there is one person here who believes through specific experience that MS Word - and many another word processor - can't fulfil all of F-H and ZioByte's requirements, please now step up and say which, and why not…

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin: "No switch between 'direct speech styles' exists" - and there you have your answer why "MS Word or any other modern word processor" is not up to the task. "an author chooses French or goodies in red" - what if the author wants to decide that it's "red" after the text is complete? "What might 'nested direct speech' mean" - please refer to common styleguides such as [this](http://www.whitesmoke.com/nested-quotations) or [this](https://www.scribbr.com/language-rules/quotation-marks/) to see examples for nested quotations. 'How could an app place marks like «» and “”' - I do ...

Comment: ... not quite see the problem. If the text is "semantically tagged" as direct speech, and the app knows which marks to place around which nesting level of direct speech, why should the app *not* be able to place such marks? "why should an app be asked to?" - that one's simple. Because at the time of writing, it doesn't play a role, it's just relevant that sentence X is direct speech. *How* exactly that is rendered, using which kind of marks, can be decided after the text is finished. Frankly, I don't think this is an outlandish requirement in any way. The concept of ...

Comment: ... [separation of content and presentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_content_and_presentation) is well established.

Comment: @F-H What you hope to achieve is unclear.

Worse, 'If the text is "semantically tagged" as direct speech, and the app knows which marks to place around which nesting level of direct speech, why should the app not be able to place such marks?' begs the real questions: how, and why?

I'm sorry to say that not only is what you suggest simple nonsense, but the fact that you continue to suggest it is increasingly offensive.

If you want to re-invent the wheel, say so.

Else please present a detailed case or stop beating your head and my ears against reality.

Comment: @F-H It seems fairly clear that if you've tried any of this, your efforts have been without tuition.

Even after all this time please, please describe a real problem instead of Posting about imaginary worries. Please?

Comment: @F-H Why is it so hard for you to see that your whole view is backwards… and if that wasn't clear, no few members would have shot me down?

Again, why not either present a detailed case or stop beating your head and my ears against reality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not been able to find any suitable Markup, so I started coding it myself.

A very preliminary version is available on [GitLab](https://gitlab.com/mcondarelli/markright).

Any feedback would be VERY welcome.

Comment: Wow, nice! Is it intended that the "\@<something>" in the Readme links to seemingly random userprofiles? Maybe you need to escape those for the Readme.

Comment: Thanks @Secespitus, of course user linking is *not* intended, but I was unable to find the right spell to disable this specific "magic". I updated README.md with more info and escaped "@", but user-pointing persists :(

Comment: Awesome! What a great idea @ZioByte . I am not too keen on actual coding, but from what I can tell  it looks like the start for an awesome project. In the next days I will tell you if some useful feedback comes to mind

Answer (score 1):

### My bestie, when converting Ebooks, is Calibre.

I use it mainly to load .epub files on my Kobo (usually converting from **.pdf or .doc**).

You have so many options to control formatting. You can also export to **.mobi** and view it on your Kindle if you own one (or also just check the given preview).

Calibre also has an integrated reader for Ebooks.

[image: Settings available]

Hope this can helps out.
Here you can find the free program:

https://calibre-ebook.com/download

Comment: Thanks @CashewsFuel, I am very much aware of both Calibre and Sigil (which I'm currently using to hand-convert), but that's *not* what I'm looking for. I would like to have some kind of "semantic" tagging which (AFAIK) is not available. Typical example would be direct-speech, where choosing different styles is not feasible (not to speak about nesting and/or differentiate based on speaker). I will update Question to reflect this. Thanks.

Comment: @ZioByte now I definitely get the whole picture. That's a beast for sure. I hope you will find it! Post it if you do, I am pretty interested as well

Comment: I started development (see my own Answer). Your feedback would be appreciated.